# powershell get-service is not showing all services defined

Tags: powershell

I'm running in powershell (as administrator):

```
get-service
```

and I'm looking for the 'Remote Desktop Services' but it is not written out by the command
The relevant part of the output is (the R's):

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
...
Stopped  RemoteAccess       Routing and Remote Access
Running  RemoteRegistry     Remote Registry
Running  RpcEptMapper       RPC Endpoint Mapper
Stopped  RpcLocator         Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator
Running  RpcSs              Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
Stopped  RSoPProv           Resultant Set of Policy Provider
...
```

However in services.msc there is:

```
Remote Desktop Services                                       Running
Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector              Running
```

Can someone please tell me why get-services is not returning 'Remote Desktop Services' and 'Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector' services?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Get-Service` orders the output by the 'Name' of the service and `Services.msc` uses the 'DisplayName'.

`Remote Desktop Services` has a 'Name' of `TermService` and `Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector` has a 'Name' of `UmRdpService`.  So neither of these would appear in the `R` section of your output, which is why you're not seeing them there.

Sort by `DisplayName` and you'll see them listed together:

```
Get-Service | Sort-Object DisplayName | Format-Table -AutoSize

...
Stopped RasAuto        Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
Running RasMan         Remote Access Connection Manager
Stopped SessionEnv     Remote Desktop Configuration
Stopped TermService    Remote Desktop Services
Stopped UmRdpService   Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector
Running RpcSs          Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
Stopped RpcLocator     Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator
Stopped RemoteRegistry Remote Registry
...
```

Comment: Thanks.
boxdog's answer is correct

Comment: @phillip-from-oz Then please accept his answer.

Comment: There is another *service* that is not shown: `RDPDR`, the "**Remote Desktop Device Redirector Driver**", you can see from: `Get-Service RDPDR | Select-Object *`. I don't understand why this is not shown in that command.

Comment: It seems to be because that service has the `ServiceType` **KernelDriver**.

Comment: Added new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76981412/why-doesnt-get-service-show-services-with-the-kerneldriver-servicetype).